# Checking if date has changed with React/Redux + Moment.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, momentjs, react-redux

I have a React+Redux application, and I display the date in it using Moment.js. I want a function to run when the date changes.

Right now I have a function to check the date:

```
  checkDate(local) {
    if (local === null) {
      localStorage.setItem('date', moment().format('MM-DD-YYYY'));
    } else if (moment(local).isBefore(moment().format('MM-DD-YYYY'))) {
      this.props.resetAll(); // This calls an action.
    }
  }
```

And if I call it manually, or refresh the page when the date changes, it works just fine. But, I want to be able to have my application run that `this.props.resetAll()` line on its own without my having to refresh the page. What would the best way be to go about it? Should it be something that happens on the Redux side of things in an action or reducer? Should I have `checkDate()` be called every X seconds or so somewhere in the component lifecycle (if so, where)?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: So you want to dispatch the action when `moment().format('MM-DD-YYYY')` changes yes? when one day turns to another.

Comment: @Shota yes, that's right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would set a timeout until 24:00 which then calls the update function:

`moment()` is defined as the current date/time, to get the difference to a specific time, you can use the `.diff()` function. So for example if you want the milliseconds till the start of the next day:

```
var msTillEndOfDay = moment().endOf('day').add(1, 'seconds').diff(moment(), 'milliseconds');
```

`.endOf('day')` would be 23:59:59 so you just add 1 seconds to have the next day.

You then simply set the Timeout with the specific update function or dispatch the right action:

```
setTimeout( () => {
    this.props.dispatch({type: 'UPDATE_DATE'})
}, msTillEndOfDay);
```

Comment: So you would put this in the reducer, then?  Or in the component?

Comment: you should use a useInterval instead. if the device goes to sleep for 2 hours, you're going to be 2 hours off .